# List of matrices in shiny

Tags: r, matrix, shiny

So, I want to create a graph of how many pixels are drown in a series of images. To do this I use the next server code

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){

observe({

centermz = input$centermz
scanmaxmz = input$scanmaxmz
scanstep = input$scanstep
scantolerance = input$scantolerance

filename = input$file$datapath

output$text1 = renderText({ 
      paste("You have selected a central mz of", centermz)})
output$text2 = renderText({ 
      paste("You have selected a maximum mz of", scanmaxmz)})
output$text3 = renderText({ 
      paste("You have selected a scan step of", scanstep)})
output$text4 = renderText({ 
      paste("You have selected a scan tolerance of", scantolerance)})
#output$text5 = renderText({ 
      #paste("You have selected this", filename)})

imagespectra = reactive({ if (is.null(input$file)){ return (NULL)}
    importImzMl(filename, centroided=TRUE)})

tables_imgs = reactive({ if (is.null(input$file)){ return (NULL)}
    tables_info_imgs(imagespectra,centermz, scanmaxmz, scansteps, scantolerance)})


array_of_used_pixels = reactive({ if (is.null(input$file)){ return (NULL)}
    as.vector(sapply(tables_imgs, sum(df!=0)))})

output$graph = reactive({ if (is.null(input$file)){ return (NULL)}
    renderPlot(array_of_used_pixels)})
```

where tables_info_imgs is a function that creates a series of matrices of used pixels per image, returning a list of matrices.

However, when I ran the script I got the next warning:

```
converting an R function to JSON as null. To change this, define a method for toJSON() for a 'function' object.
```

So, apparently I cannot run the function because nor do the graph because I need to convert everything to a Java compatible. How can I solve this? Is there a way to get around that?